# Declare a SymPy symbol non-zero

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way to make Symbol non-zero in sympy?
For example if I integrate:

```
psi = a * cos( sqrt(2/mu)*x ) + b * sin( sqrt(2/mu)*x )
Psi = integrate(psi, x)
```

it gives me two results one for mu == 0 and  one for mu != 0. And I only need the second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `mu = Symbol('mu', nonzero=True)`.

```
from sympy import *
a,b,x = symbols('a b x')
mu = Symbol('mu', nonzero=True)
psi = a * cos( sqrt(2/mu)*x ) + b * sin( sqrt(2/mu)*x )
Psi = integrate(psi, x)
```

Now `Psi` is a single expression.

Reference: [assumptions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.assumptions).

Comment: Worth noting: `nonzero=True` means "real and not zero", whereas `zero=False` just means "not zero". It could make a difference if the variables could be complex valued.